# Creating Nondeterministic functions in SQL Server using RAND()

Tags: sql, function, non-deterministic

After a bit of searching and reading the documentation, it's clear that you can write user defined functions in SQL Server that are marked as either deterministic or nondeterministic depending on which built-infunctions are used within the body.

RAND() is listed under the nondeterministic functions (see [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx)). So why can't I use it in a function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because it has side effects.

Constructs with side effects are not allowed in a function. The side effect that it has is to change some internal state that keeps track of the last `rand()` value issued.

I think you can get around it by including it in a View definition then selecting from the View.

Comment: ah, I understand now! I didn't think about the internal storage of the last random number. I can see how this sets it apart from other nondeterministic functions. Thanks!

Comment: check out http://sqlfascination.com/tag/randomstring/  It tells you exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 19):

Using a View might work for you.
From [Returning Random Numbers from a select statement](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/22/2927.aspx)

```
CREATE VIEW vRandNumber
AS
SELECT RAND() as RandNumber
```

The view is necessary because, as you already found out, a UDF cannot use the rand() function because that would make the function non-determistic. You can trick the UDF to accept a random number by using a View.

```
CREATE FUNCTION RandNumber()
RETURNS float
AS
  BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT RandNumber FROM vRandNumber)
  END
```

Finally, you can use this function in any SELECT to now return a random number between 0 and 1 per row:

```
SELECT dbo.RandNumber(), *
FROM Northwind..Customers
```

Comment: +1 For the view trick. I just remembered about that as well. It isn't because of the determinism though. `getdate()` is allowed in a function. Obviously that function can't be then used where a deterministic function is required such as a persisted computed column. It is because of the side effects. The error raised is "Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'rand' within a function."

Comment: Thanks! I'd heard about doing this as a work around for the NEWID() function, but didn't realise it would work for RAND() as well.

Answer (score 4):

I found this [solution](https://ssdba.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/using-or-simulating-rand-in-a-t-sql-user-defined-function/) that doesn't create a view:

Basically:

Instead of

```
SET @R = Rand()
```

Use

```
SET @R = ABS(CHECKSUM(PWDENCRYPT(N''))) / 2147483647.0
```

In my case I wanted a number between 1 and 10:

```
ROUND(((10 - 1 -1) * ( ABS(CHECKSUM(PWDENCRYPT(N''))) / 2147483647.0) + 1), 0))

ROUND(((@max - @lower -1) * ( ABS(CHECKSUM(PWDENCRYPT(N''))) / 2147483647.0) + @lower), 0))
```

If you want a full explanation: [Using (Or Simulating) Rand() In A T-Sql User-Defined Function](https://ssdba.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/using-or-simulating-rand-in-a-t-sql-user-defined-function/)